# Return from included file

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to return from a required file? It seems the return statement is only allowed inside methods/lambdas.

Comment: You shouldn't execute much code at the top-level of a required file, so what would be the use of it?

Comment: It's for a rails initializer, I would like to execute it only if a certain gem has been included, and would like to avoid enclosing everything inside an if block. Not a big deal anyway, but I just was curious if ruby had something like this.

Comment: I suggest you just wrap it in an `if` block. It might seem strange to you but actually it's not uncommon to do such things in Ruby. +1 for @tadman

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always wrap a large portion of your code in a conditional. Since Ruby allows these nearly anywhere you can even conditionally declare classes:

```
if (defined?(Something))
  class SomeClass
    # ...
  end
end
```

This is not unlike C with `#ifdef` but doesn't require a separate language. It's the standard way of doing things even if you think it seems odd.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do a return statement on top level:

```
return unless defined(Something)

class SomeClass
  # body
end
```

Comment: I don't think it was part of ruby when this question was asked though: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4840